# How to sort xpath using php

Tags: php, xpath

i searched through the website and couldnt find exact result for my question.

i need to search through the xml file and sort the output by the order in date descending.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
  <entry>
    <date>1299565881</date>
    <action>made an action under category</action>
    <user>Admin</user>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <date>1299566115</date>
    <action>Item deleted</action>
    <user>Admin</user>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

here is my code

```
<?php

$data = simplexml_load_file($filename);

if($to_date_int>$global_date)
    $op = $data->xpath('/entries/entry[date<='.$to_date_int.']');
else
    $op = $data->xpath('/entries/entry');
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? You want to sort each entry by date, then what?

Comment: XPath is not a good tool for sorting, either pre-sort with XSLT or post-sort with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$op` will be an array of the matching `entry` elements, you could use PHP's array sorting functions to sort by their associated `date` elements.

```
function sort_entries_by_date($a, $b) {
    return (int) $b->date - (int) $a->date;
}
usort($op, 'sort_entries_by_date');
```

<sup>(If you're using PHP 5.3, the named function could be placed by an inline anonymous function.)</sup>

Comment: Works fine., thank u salathe.,
Can u explain me how does the function actually works !?
what happens in the line
    return (int)$b->date - (int)$a->date;
Thanks again.

Comment: The sort function must return `0` if the values are to be considered the same, `less than zero` if `$a` is to appear lower than `$b` in the sorted array, or `greater than zero` otherwise (`$a` will appear higher than `$b`).  So my function will sort the entries by descending date order (because if the date in `$a` is greater than that in `$b`, the function will return a negative number). As for the maybe strange `(int)$b->date` syntax, that's just getting the integer value of the `<date>` element belonging to the `<entry>` held in `$b`.